# text object in Vim (moving between text object)

Tags: vim, macvim

I have two words:

```
word1  word2
```

I do:

```
c2iw
```

for changing two entire world but it doesn't work and it's the same for selecting:

```
v2iw
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works, but you need to count the <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> commands, not the words.  If the cursor is on a space, <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> selects the spaces between words.  In your case the first <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> would refer to the first word, a second one to the space(s) between words, and a third one to the second word.  Thus, you need <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>.  Can't blame Vim for too much consistency. :)

Comment: Excellent explanations.

Answer (score 1):

`iw` covers `word1` and `word2` but it also covers the whitespace between the two:

```
word1 word2
-----          iw
------         2iw
-----------    3iw
```

The correct command is thus:

```
<operator>3iw
```

or:

```
3<operator>iw
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to jump to the next text object.
You do this by using e.

```
e
```

The next step would be to change the two words that are next.

```
c2e
```

Change the next two text objects.
For selecting them:

```
v2e
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the `iw` motion considers the spaces as words too. So, if u don't want to be bothered about those spaces and target the **words as you know them**, use `aw` motion.

So, instead of doing this:

```
c3iw
v3iw
```

just do this:

```
c2aw
v2aw
```

Then Vim will not consider the **space** character as a word.